# Middleware no aparece en mi vista - Usando Node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, middleware

Actualmente estoy realizando o reproduciendo un servidor incluyendo la construccion de su svistas.
Tengo un problema con la aplicación de un middleware desde la pagina index hasta las vistas, de manera de hacer las paginas mucho mas dinamicas.

Las variables que cree son titulo de la pagina y ano de creacion de la pagina.

Estoy utilizando el metodo app.use, donde const app = express();

Les comparto el código para que me ayuden a ubicar cual es el error.

```
app.use ( (req, res, next) => {
    const year = New Date();
    res.locals.actualYear = year.getFullYear();
    next();
})
```

donde Req es la carga de la pagina y res, es aparecer esa variable en la vista que escoja.

Cuando corro el programa del servidor aparece que la variable no esta definida, sin embargo, en la teoría de la documentacion de Express(), entiendo que la variable se adiciona con marcarla sobre el objeto.

Lo que quiero que aparezca es la fecha del año actual, en el template de pug.

```
footer.container.py-5   
    .row    
        .col-md-6 
            nav.nav.footer.justify-content-center.justify-content-md-start 
                    a.nav-link(href="/nosotros") Nosotros
                    a.nav-link(href="/viajes") Viajes
                    a.nav-link(href="/testimoniales") Testimoniales
        .col
            p.copyright.text-center.text-md-right 
                |Todos los derechos reservado 
                span= actualYear
```

En sintaxis de pug.
La idea es que aparezca en ese layout del footer el año actual que estamos.

Me podrian indicar porque no se ve ningun middleware en mis vistas por favor?

Muchas gracias

Comment: como estas incluyendo este middleware ? otra cosa, agrega tu middleware entero

Comment: estoy agregandolo en la vista hecha con pug, de manera directa, solo la variable.

Comment: deberias mostrar tu middleware completo y detallado, en que ruta lo esta utilizando, que es lo que haces y cual es el resultado que esperas, para ti puede ser obvio, los usuarios de so no sabemos bien a lo que te refieres, por ese motivo pedimos que tu pregunta este bien detallada

Comment: @Enzo todo bien que los usuarios de so no sepan a lo que me refiero, por eso modifiqué la pregunta, quizas este un poco mas clara. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis en la linea: `const year = New Date();`. La palabra reservada `new` se escribe en minúsculas. Debería ser: `const year = new Date();`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar @MauricioContreras

Comment: Coloca ese middleware antes del middleware que recibe la solicitud y lo renderiza.